# Conversion constructor

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, destructor

Can any one tell me how the char* member gets deleted after conversion constructor is called.

The output is Debug Assertion Failed

```
class String
{
public:
    char* m;
    String()
    {
        m = NULL;
    }
    String(const char* str)
    {
        m = strdup(str);
    }
    String(const String& I)
    {
        m = strdup(I.m);
    }
    ~String()
    {
        delete m;
    }
};


void main()
{
    String s;
    s = "abc";
    s = "bcd";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's analyze `s = "abc"`:**

First of all, this is an assignment, not an instantiation, because `s` has already been declared.

So the compilation solution for this would be to create a temporary `String` object with `"abc"` as the argument to the `String` constructor, and then call the `String` assignment operator in order to copy that temporary object into `s`.

Now, since you have not implemented an assignment operator for this class, the default assignment operator is called, and simply copies each one of the member variables from the temporary `String` object into `s`.

Finally, the temporary `String` object is destroyed and the memory pointed by its `m` variable is deallocated. As a result, you end up with `s.m` pointing to an invalid piece of memory.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have not implemented an assignment operator. So when you do this

```
s = "abc";
```

you end up with two `String` objects (one of them a temporary) holding a pointer to the same address. They both try to delete the same object. You need to follow [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

**Note**: as @kolrabi has pointed out, you should be calling `free` on a pointer allocated with `strdup`, not `delete`.

Comment: I up-voted, but you could have been less of an a** in the comments.

Comment: @StoryTeller Fair enough, sorry!

Comment: Also the return value from `strdup()` should be `free()`d not `delete`d.